# Visitor design pattern

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

Is that possible that the accept method for the visitor design pattern can be implemented by the root of the class hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that if Java allowed you to implement `accept` only once, in the base class, that very fact would defeat the entire purpose of Visitor, which is a very cumbersome workaround for the missing multiple dispatch in Java and other similar languages.

Answer (score 0):

In a manner of speaking, yes, but a proper Visitor implementation would require that your base-class implementation have an if chain that checks what subclass of the base class `this` is an instance of, since, as others have pointed out, the purpose of the Visitor pattern is to achieve something like multiple dispatch, which requires distinguishing the runtime type of an object in some way. I.e, you either implement Visitor the "right" way, with an `accept()` in each subclass that can be dispatched to, or you implement one big `accept()` in the root of the hierarchy that looks like:

```
public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
    if (this instanceof Foo) {
        doSomething();
    } else if (this instanceof Bar) {
        doSomethingElse();
    } else ...
}
```

Not very pretty, eh? It violates all kinds of design principles, including proper polymorphic design, which is the whole point of the Visitor and multiple dispatch, so on second thought, I think it'd be a stretch to call that Visitor at all.

Comment: Might be better to call it the "no visitors" pattern :-)

Comment: Not true! the accept class gets a visitor and it calls the visitors visit method, it will go to the visitor you send to it, you should absolutely not use instanceof

Comment: see my answer, the only reason that you need to implement the accept method multiple time (and its identical in all of them) is because you want to use an interface and not to extend a class just to have a visitor.
In java you can extend just one class, you dont want to waste that just because you dont want to duplicate a simple one line function

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the accept method in the base class, but then you can't implement any other classes because you can only extend one class, you dont want to waste that just because you dont want to duplicate a simple one line function

Answer (score -1):

In Java this is not possible because the compiler would not know what method to bind to. (Some languages have dynamic method binding based on the actual runtime class of an object, but not Java.)

Comment: I'm still confused... isn't Visitor exactly the pattern used to solve the problem of double dispatch? If Java had double dispatch, then there would never be a reason to bother with Visitor in the first place, right?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Exactly. Java doesn't have double dispatch, so it needs the Visitor pattern. For the same reason, the `accept` method cannot be implemented by the base class. The GoF book specifically says that the visitor pattern is a way of implementing double dispatch.

Comment: Yes, so if OP could implement `accept` only in the base class, then he wouldn't be implementing `accept` in the first place -- so, once again, he wouldn't be implementing `accept` in the base class. It's circular logic akin to the anthropic principle -- the only reason you're doing it is **because** you need it every step of the way down the hierarchy :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Right you are. If it could be done, you wouldn't need to do it. More like Catch-22, I think, than the anthropic principle (which isn't circular logic). I think you made the point very nicely in your answer.

Comment: You could imagine the `accept` method asking itself "Why am I being reimplemented in every class?" - "Silly idea - if I wasn't, there would be no *me* asking that question" :)

Comment: Marko I am sorry but you are wrong, java always goes to the deepest object (e.g. if you have B that extends A, and you send B to a function that accepts A, if you call function f() then if will go to B's function if it has it. thats the whole "trick" in the visitor pattern